# How to do a very complicated integral involving trig functions?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to do this complicated integral:

$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{(t-c-\pi)(2 \cos(t-b) \sin(t-b) \cos(t-c) \sin(t-c)-2 \sin(t-b) \sin(t-c)+2 \cos(t-b)^2 \cos(t-c)^2-(\cos(t-c)+\cos(t-b))^2+2)}{(\cos(t-c)-\cos(t-b))^3 \sin(t-c)} dt$$

What makes it complicated is some of the values are shifted by $b$ and some by $c$.

Any ideas how to proceed from here? Do you think it is possible to solve this to get an answer in terms of $b$ and $c$ ? What method should I use? Or at least turn it into a nicer looking integral!

Comment: I don't even want to look at it.

Comment: @MatthewPilling lol. Avert thine eyes.

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is split it up by using linearity of the integral.

Comment: What on earth... Can you do some numerical experiments?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: It is part of a calculation of the minimum energy of a circular membrane calculating a term in a Green's function G(b,c) where b and c are angle to two points on the boundary. Probably not the best way to do it. But then again, it might never have been done before.

Comment: On second thoughts it probably doesn't converge because of a pole at $t=c$